# Sql Analysis Services Current Date

Tags: mdx, ssas, calculated-field

I need to perform a calculation in SSAS which only applies to the current and future months (it can't be applied retrospectively using the available data).

I can do this by using the calendar hierarchy and hard coding today's month as follows...

```
SCOPE([Measures].[RollingStock]);        
    ([Dim Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[201008]:NULL) = 
    ([Measures].[Quantity On Hand] 
     - [Measures].[SO Open Quantity] 
     + [Measures].[PO Open Quantity] 
     - [Measures].[Forecasts Quantity]);        
END SCOPE;
```

I want to replace 201008 with the current month (in that format).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE SET CURRENTCUBE.[Current And Future Months]
 AS {
StrToMember("[Dim Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[" + Format(now(), "yyyyMM") + "]"):NULL
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that should do it. Use VBA to create a string which will match the member name, and then convert the string into a set.

Comment: It is better to use Date() instead of Now() for performance reasons.Chris Webb explains the reason here - http://cwebbbi.wordpress.com/2009/09/10/now-and-the-formula-cache/.