# How to calculate current month and next 6 months in an mdx query ?? Please help !

Tags: mdx

i want to calculate current month and next 6 months in an mdx query as columns..Please help !!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this within MDX, and it can be a pain. String manipulation with VBA was the most accurate way, but there are MDX-only shortcuts (that can be unreliable). See this thread, which links to another:
[how to get latest date in mdx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536359/how-to-get-latest-date-in-mdx/3557849#3557849)

Answer (score 0):

To get current month, you can use below code:

WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Current Month] AS
    VBAMDX.Format(VBAMDX.Now(),"MM")
SELECT
  {[Measures].[Current Month]} ON COLUMNS
FROM [Analysis Services Tutorial];