# Advanced MDX query

Tags: mdx, business-intelligence

I am in a process of making OLAP cubes for data mining purposes.

The domain is Instruments which run tests and tests has status id's 1,2,3 which means ok, warning and error. I have already deployed the cube and its working perfectly.
My measure is the Sum of my tests. I have a timetable associated with the test table, for when the test was run.

I have four dimensions:

Instrument: which holds information about instrument.

Test: contains all the tests with information about the time it ran.

Status: contains the three status mentioned above.

Time: sort out tests in time

My question is, I have another status called 'NotRun'. Like the other statuses NotRun tests can not be saved in the database, but is calculated with a query.

Notrun is calculated by selecting all instruments from instrument table and then extract those instruments that are to find in test table within a given time period.

I want to use MDX to do the thing mentioned above, but instead of giving a time period i want the cube to handle that for me dynamically.

I don't want to pick a specific year instead i would like to take care of that with my time dimension dynamically.

where ([Date].[Calendar Year].&[2002])

I am really stucked. Any idea how we can acheive that in Business Studio Intelligence 2008?

All the best,
Hassan.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question "how do I get MDX to pick a date member by itself" see my answer at [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536359/how-to-get-latest-date-in-mdx/3557849#3557849)

Or did you want Business Studio Intelligence to pop up a box and ask for the dates each time you run the report?

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will try that and see if it works for me. About the business studio intelligence to pop up a box and ask for the dates each time the report is run, is this possible if yes then can you give me an example?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know if that is possible. I was just trying to understand what your question actually was!