# Getting data for past 6 months in MDX

Tags: mdx, reporting-services

I am using SSRS to create reports. For the metrics i am pulling out data from the analysis services. I want to modify the mdx query created by the query designer to include data only from past 6 months. The query looks like this right now:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Cumulative Count] } ON COLUMNS, 
        NON EMPTY { ([Work Item].[Microsoft_VSTS_Common_Discipline].[Microsoft_VSTS_Common_Discipline].ALLMEMBERS * [Date].[Year Month Date].[Month].ALLMEMBERS ) } 
        DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 
        FROM 
          ( SELECT ( { [Work Item].[System_WorkItemType].&[Task] } ) ON COLUMNS 
        FROM 
          ( SELECT ( { [Date].[Year Month Date].[Year].&[2010-01-01T00:00:00] } ) ON COLUMNS FROM [Team System])) 
       WHERE ( [Work Item].[System_WorkItemType].&[Task] ) CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS*
```

Here I am pulling out the cumulative count of the work items where the work item type is task and the year of the work item is 2010. However instead of pulling out all the months from 2010 i want past 6 months. Does anyone know how can i do this in the above query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new calculated member that returns data for only the last 6 months.

Comment: can you please explain how ca I do that in a little more detail? I am new to SSRS..

Comment: Check this link out, it has many good examples: http://www.ssas-info.com/ssas-cheat-sheets/72-cheat-sheets/880-time-mdx-cheat-sheets

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in the past by adding VBA functions to my MDX (Analysis Services allows this). You can get the current date, work back 6 months, grab the month/year, and write a string in the same format as your member names. Then use `StrToSet` to include this string in your MDX query.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512028/sql-analysis-services-current-date